# Clipping in ArcGIS

Tags: arcgis-desktop, shapefile

I have a map and I want to cut out my study area. How can I do this in ArcGIS?

Comment: You need to start by georeferencing the paper map, see: http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/manage-data/raster-and-images/fundamentals-for-georeferencing-a-raster-dataset.htm

Comment: I know that, but my problem is to cut a specific part and show its coordinates so that I can use it to create a geological map. – BERA

Comment: Use the Clip geoproccessing tool

Comment: Lots of missing details here...   Has the *picture* been georeferenced? Is the *specific part* in a polygon layer? Have you tried any geoprocessing at all? GIS SE is a *problem-solving* site,  not a *task-doing* one. You need to make a good-faith effort and document the problem encountered before we can help.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is touched upon in the comments, but to elaborate on a few things:

As Stated, you will first need to georeference the scanned version of the paper map. It would be easiest if you georeference the whole map first and then look to extract out your study area, as chances are you will be able to find more georeferencing coordinates in the full map.

BERA mentioned using the "CLIP" Geoprocessing tool. It should be noted that there are two CLIP Tools in ArcMap. One is for Vector Data and the other for raster. Because you are using clipping out an area for a raster image, you will need to use the Clip Function for Raster datatypes. This is found:

ArcToolbox ->  Data Management Tools -> Raster -> Raster Processing - Clip

The clip function here will only clip a square / rectangle, you can use a layer as a template to define the bounding coordinates in the tool.

If you are looking to use a study area which is not a regular rectangle or square, you can use the Spatial Analyst Extract by Mask Tool. This tools lets you use the actual shape of a boundary as the template to extract information. This tools works and produces a result similar to the Vector Clip geoprocessing tool. The tool is found:

Arc Toolbox -> Spatial Analyst -> Extraction -> Extract by Mask

If you do not have access to Spatial Analyst, you can mimic the result of the tool but using the dataframe clipping options.

1. Open the Data Frame Properties Window
2. Click the "Data Frame" tab
3. The last options in the window are "Clip Options", you need to click on the drop down list and choose "Clip to Shape", then "Specify Shape"
4. In the new dialog, select the section radio button "Outline of Features", choose any other options you feel you may want (Visible, Selection etc), hit ok
5. The next part is important, choose the "Exclude Layers" and choose all the data in here you want to be visible outside of the clipping boundary (aerial imagery, background information etc)
6. Lastly, untick the "Clip Grids and Graticules" this will ensure your map grid is not cut off at the clipping boundary.